# GridLayout RecyclerView with layout_height="wrap_content"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

The items in my RecyclerView Grid are stretched automatically if the left item is shorter and the right item is taller or vice versa (2 grid spans) because I want to use layout_height="wrap_content". How to keep that left item from being stretched automatically? I still want to use the GridLayout style because in my case it is not suitable if using StaggeredGridLayout (because it is more suitable for photo galleries).

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/very_light_gray"
    android:paddingBottom="61dp"
    tools:context="Fragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        ...

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_explore_buyer_outlet"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:paddingBottom="28dp"       
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:spanCount="2"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
            tools:itemCount="18"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_grid" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

---

```
item_grid.xml

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="177dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_14sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_14sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_minus18sdp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="14dp"
    app:cardElevation="1dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_item_outlet_buyer_photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:importantForAccessibility="no"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/outlet10"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_item_outlet_buyer_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
            android:background="@drawable/outlet_buyer_status_open_label"
            android:fontFamily="@font/notosansjp_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3.75dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="10sp"    
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_item_outlet_buyer_photo"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp"
            tools:text="Open" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_item_outlet_buyer_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10.5dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/notosansjp_bold"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="1.5dp"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_17sdp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_item_outlet_buyer_photo"
            tools:text="Guttenburg, Alazka" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_item_outlet_buyer_dotted_line"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:importantForAccessibility="no"
            android:layerType="software"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dotted_shape"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tv_item_outlet_buyer_name" 
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_item_outlet_buyer_name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_item_outlet_buyer_name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_item_outlet_buyer_category"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4.5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/notosansjp_regular"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="1.5dp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_item_outlet_buyer_dotted_line"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp"
            tools:text="Food ∙ Drink ∙ Snack" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**I want make my GridLayout like this (edited in Figma):**
[image]

**But I got like this if last textView have constraintBottom_toBottomOf(parent):**
[image]

**And, I got like this if last textView not have constraintBottom_toBottomOf(parent):**
[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Add a linearLayout for every line and put the two pictures inside it

Comment: should use LinearLayout or can use ConstraintLayout? and what does "two pictures" mean? Is it making drawable as background of item?

Comment: You currently have a recyclerView with spanCount 2, use one instead and wrap two pictures inside of a container and put this container in the recyclerView, that will make sure, that both pictures in a column consume the same amount of space (one of them +empty space)

Comment: use spanCount 1, and make 2 cardView horizontally in item layout? if so, how about the id name of the view?
or is there any sample code I can use?

Comment: Sorry, I'm currently not on my PC. You can add a new xml, just the container + 2 cardViews, and then access both cardsViews via there id

Comment: Okay no problem, but.. about the id of view in item layout xml, what should I do (eg. tv_name_left for the left column, and tv_name_right for the right column)? Because can't create same name id in 1 layout XML file

Comment: Yeah, these names sound good

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure your `TextView`'s `layout_height` is `wrap_content`, and give *that* the black background. The containing layout should be transparent, so when it resizes to fit the grid, the extra space is just "empty". The `TextView` shouldn't resize with it (and neither should anything else in the item's layout), so the black area stays the same - the extra height is unused.

Here's a quick example

```
MainFragment.kt

class MainFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_main) {

    lateinit var binding: FragmentMainBinding

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        // fragment_main.xml has a RecyclerView in it with "recycler" for its ID
        binding = FragmentMainBinding.bind(view)
        with(binding) {
            recycler.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2)
            recycler.adapter = Adapterino(requireContext())
        }
    }

    private class Adapterino(val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapterino.ViewHolder>() {

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder =
            ItemViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context)).run(::ViewHolder)

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            // just generating random amounts of text to get some variation
            holder.binding.textView.text =
                generateSequence { "cats" }.take(Random.nextInt(5, 20)).joinToString(" ")
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int = 20

        private class ViewHolder(val binding: ItemViewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
    }

}
```

```
item_view.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: An example image of the RecyclerView with a GridLayout where items in each row have variable heights]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.. but, can you give example in this structure (below)? Because i've problem if using LinearLayout about my design (because i'm rarely use LinearLayour, always ConstraintLayout).

**grandpa** `CardView (W 177dp, H wrap_content)`
-- **father** `ConstraintLayout (W match_parent, H match_parent)`
---- **son** `ImageView (W match_parent, H 112dp)`
---- **son** `TextView (W 0dp, H wrap_content)`

I've change height of last TextView to wrap_content, but the height of CardView still auto-stretched.

Comment: @Villa the `LinearLayout` was just a simple example to illustrate the idea. The point is the outer container stretches to fit the height of the current row in the `GridLayout`, so if you don't want your `CardView` to stretch, that can't be the outer view. So if you put your `CardView` inside a `FrameLayout` or something, that FrameLayout can stretch. Make the CardView's height `wrap_content`, as well as everything inside it without a fixed size (including the `ConstraintLayout`), and the actual card will only be as tall as its contents